# Pass local variable in function to outside function

Tags: r, function, object

I'm trying to pass the symbol function from my readline/input function (readstock)

```
readinteger <- function()
 {
  symbol <- readline(prompt="Enter an symbol: ")
  return(as.character(symbol))
 }

# return df of stock value for x history

readinteger()

stock <- paste("YAHOO/",symbol)

df <- Quandl(stock)
```

Why does this not return an object for symbol that I can call in my paste?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Got it! Simply use the full function call as an object!

```
stock <- paste("YAHOO/",readstock())
```